# garbage being inserted at the end of char array after filling different char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

```
char test1[4];
    test1[0] = '\0';

    test1[0] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[1] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[2] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[3] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[4] = '\0';

    cout << test1 << endl;


    char test2[5];
    test2[0] = '\0';

    test2[0] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[1] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[2] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[3] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[4] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);

    cout << test1 << endl;
```

example output:

```
vtcr
vtcrewpcs

uqyr
uqyrvygqx

nqoh
nqohlhuuq
```

I'm trying to write a method that generates a string. I thought I'd use a char array since I was planning on iterating over it like you would any other array, but I keep running into issues with random garbage being inserted. This chunk of code was made just to try and figure stuff out, but I'm running into issues that I just don't understand.

why does filling a completely unrelated char array cause the first array to return garbage when printed to the command line?

Should I just use a normal string instead? If so, how do you fill a string with chars?

ALSO i was never taught to use a char array instead of a string, this is my first time doing so, I wanted to use one because an array filled with chars seemed like exactly what I needed, but it seems that char arrays do not act like literally any other array >:(

ALSO ALSO, i am filling them like that because this was just meant to be a learning exercise. I will be using a for loop and will only randomly generate the first letter.

ALSO ALSO ALSO, this is in main, the rest looks like this:

```
int main() {
    cout << boolalpha;
    srand(time(NULL));

    ...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You're indexing past the end of your arrays. If you define an array with 4 elements, then you can only access indices 0, 1, 2, 3. It's okay to index one-past-the-end if all you want is a pointer, but if you read from or write to that address it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Side-notes: 1) Avoid hard-coding values like 97 when you meant to use the character literal `'a'`; 2) Note that this only works for some character encodings like ASCII and is not portable, because not all encodings represent alphabetic characters sequentially; 3) Modulo by 25 will return a maximum of 24, meaning you exclude the character `'z'`; 4) The use of `rand()` in C++ is highly discouraged; 5) Consider using `std::string` from the standard library, and you can just push characters onto it without worrying about NULL termination.

Comment: `test1[4] = '\0';` - that's undefined behaviour right there. You declared an array of 4 elements, now you are writing to the fifth. Why are you writing outside of the memory you allocated? Remember, array indexing starts at `0`.

Comment: Thank you Paddy for such a timely response! I'll try to internalize all of your advice (I kinda like rand() though, at least for casual projects). I'm gonna see if I can figure out char arrays some more, but I'll probably end up using std::string.

Comment: yeah it seems like the issue is completely caused by exceeding the memory I allocated, IDK why I thought it would be fine to do so just because It was a null character.

how do I mark this as SOLVED

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indexing past the end of your array. If you define an array with 4 elements, then you can only access indices 0, 1, 2, 3. It's okay to index one-past-the-end if all you want is a pointer, but if you read from or write to that address it is undefined behavior.

It's also pointless to write the NULL terminator to the first element, and then overwrite it with some other data. It looks like you expected this to do some kind of magical string termination, but there's nothing magic about arrays.

So, what you're seeing is undefined behavior. You attempted to NULL-terminate the string, but wrote outside of the array bounds into memory not occupied by that array. So the contents of that memory location are indeterminate, if your program doesn't immediately crash.

When you try to output the string, `std::cout` keeps scanning memory looking for a NULL terminator, and in this case doesn't find one until later.

For your code to work, you must use larger arrays. At the very least:

```
char test1[5];
char test2[6];

// Note that you also need to terminate `test2`, which you did not do.
// Although technically you never output that string, so it wouldn't
// change anything.
```

> Should I just use a normal string instead? If so, how do you fill a string with chars?

Yes. In most cases, just use `std::string` unless you have a really specific reason why you need to use an array. Such reasons are typically related to avoiding the use of dynamic memory. You can use the [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) method to append characters:

```
std::string make_random_string(size_t size)
{
    std::string foo;
    foo.reserve(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        foo.push_back('a' + rand() % 26);
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Note the [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) is not strictly necessary, but polite. If you know how much data you need, then always be up-front about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    char test1[4];
    test1[0] = '\0';   // Not needed

    test1[0] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[1] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[2] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test1[3] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);   // should be '\0' here

    test1[4] = '\0';   // this is out of bound. Index only up to 3 (size 4)

    cout << test1 << endl;


    char test2[5];
    test2[0] = '\0';     // Not needed

    test2[0] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[1] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[2] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[3] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);
    test2[4] = char((rand() % 25) + 97);    //should be '\0' here

    cout << test1 << endl;
```

Or should create additional 1 space for '\0' e.g.

```
char test1[5];  // 4 characters + '\0'
...
test1[4] = '\0';

char test2[6];  // 5 characters + '\0'
...
test2[5] = '\0';
```